# UICollectionViewCell's contentView background layers over the content

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView that uses UICollectionViewCell

```
collectionView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CustomCell.identifier)
```

And I am using isSelected variable to change the background of selected cell.

```
class CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isSelected {
                self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#f0f0f0")
                
            } else {
                self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }
        }
    }
```

But the background color is applied over the content of the cell like this below.

[image]

It was not like this on ios 13. I think it started to happen from ios 14 or 15. Any idea? Thank you in advance.

---

EDIT:

```
class CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
    let myImage: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()
    
    let myLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Custom Text"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        return label
    }()
    
    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(myImage)
        addSubview(myLavel)
        
        /*setup auto layout*/
    }
    
    static var identifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isSelected {
                self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#f0f0f0")
                
            } else {
                self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let customCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CustomCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        customCell.myLabel.text = "Pepe"
        customCell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: "pepe")
        return categoryCell
    }
```

Comment: How are you adding the images to the cell?

Comment: your image is not inside contentView. it's below contentView...

Comment: updated the post with more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Fahim Parkar, the below fixed the issue.

```
        contentView.addSubview(myImage)
        contentView.addSubview(myLavel)
```